# Validating partially filled objects

Tags: c#, validation, error-handling, hash-map

The following classes are a simplification of an auto-generated code of an ORM (targeting Microsoft's Dynamics CRM):

```
public class Entity 
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Fields { get; set;}
    public virtual T GetFieldValue<T>(string fieldName)
    {
         return (T)Fields[fieldName];
    }
    protected virtual void SetFieldValue(string fieldName, object value)
    {
         Fields[fieldName] = value;
    }
}
partial class Account : Entity
{
    public string Name
    get
    {
         return GetFieldValue<string>("Name");
    }
    set
    {
         SetFieldValue("Name", value);
    }
    public string Email
    get
    {
         return GetFieldValue<string>("Email");
    }
    set
    {
         SetFieldValue("Email", value);
    }
}
```

When an `Entity`'s derived class is retrieved from the database, the base class `Fields` property is automatically assigned (again, this is not something in my control) with the selected fields.

I'd like a review of the following class, intended to validate "partially" filled objects:

```
public class EntitySubset<T> : Entity where T : Entity
{
    public EntitySubset(T subset)
    {
        foreach (var field in subset.Fields)
        {
            SetFieldValue(field.Key, field.Value);
        }
    }
    public override U GetFieldValue<U>(string fieldName)
    {
        if (!Fields.ContainsKey(fieldName))
        {
            throw new Exception($"{typeof(T).Name} must contain {fieldName} as a key!");
        }
        return base.GetFieldValue<U>(fieldName);
    }
}
```

an example usage:

```
private List<Account> GetSimiliarAccounts(EntitySubset<Account> targetAccount)
{
    var similarityFields = new[] { "Name", "Email" };
    var similiarAccounts = db.Where(account =>
       similarityFields.All(f => 
          account.GetFieldValue<object>(f) == targetAccount.GetFieldValue<object>(f))
    ).ToList();
    return similiarAccounts;
}
```

so that if `GetSimiliarAccounts` is called as follows:

```
GetSimiliarAccounts(new EntitySubset<Account>(new Account { Email = "b" }));
```

then the output is:

```
System.Exception: 'Account must contain Name as a key!'
```

Note that `EntitySubset<T>` and its error messaging is intended for developers to "fail fast", namely: to quickly spot and fix bugs stemming from a partially filled object.

What do you think of `EntitySubset<T>` as a validation implementation?

Comment: Good to see your question back up, and with sufficient context.

Comment: Nothing ever is irrelevant around here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Review

You should avoid hardcoded strings. Take advantage of `nameof`. Also, *expression-bodied members* (arrow notation) makes code cleaner to read.

```
public string Name
{
    get => GetFieldValue<string>(nameof(Name));
    set => SetFieldValue(nameof(Name), value);
}
```

`EntitySubset<T>`'s method `GetFieldValue` makes sure a clean (but technical) error message is thrown whenever an asked field is not available.

> ```
> public override U GetFieldValue<U>(string fieldName)
> {
>     if (!Fields.ContainsKey(fieldName))
>     {
>         throw new Exception($"{typeof(T).Name} must contain {fieldName} as a key!");
>     }
>     return base.GetFieldValue<U>(fieldName);
> }
> ```

However, don't fallback to this method to perform business rules checks. The business layer should check that mandatory fields are filled in, before mapping the entities to the data layer.

You should also optimize `ContainsKey` and `base.GetFieldValue`. You don't want to perform 2 lookups here. Implement something like a `TryGetFieldValue`.

Comment: *"The business layer should check that mandatory fields are filled in"*: well, that's the purpose of `EntitySubset<T>`. Don't you consider it part of the business layer?

Comment: Perhaps so, but it's very generic (unspecific). I would argue you need a layer on top with specific rules and error messages tailored to the end-user. _EntitySubset_ is a last resort fallback (in my opinion).

Comment: I should've clarified (and I'm going to edit it into the question) that `EntitySubset<T>` and its error messaging is intended for developers to "fail fast", not for users. Note that an alternative input parameter for `GetSimiliarAccounts` is `Account`.

Comment: You may edit the question to stipulate it's a technical error. That re-enforces the need for additional business rule validation a layer higher up the stack.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example for such additional business rule validation? I'm not sure what else is needed that is not already handled by `EntitySubset<T>`.

Comment: Well business rules could check, not only on existence of the field, but also content. For instance, _if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Account.Name)) throw .._